# A question on Galois groups and deformations of Galois coverings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, automorphism-groups

I've recently been working on several problems related to deformations of Galois covers of projective space, and have come across the following situation: If $X$ is a projective variety and $G$ is a (finite) subgroup of automorphisms of $X$, let $\pi_G:X\to X/G$ be the quotient map. We can get a family of Galois covers of $X/G$ by considering the map $\pi_G\circ\sigma^{-1}$ for $\sigma\in\mathrm{Aut}^0(X)$, which is just the quotient map for the group $\sigma G\sigma^{-1}$. I'm particularly interested in the case when $X/G\simeq\mathbb{P}^n$. My question is the following:

Does there exist a projective variety $X$ and a continuous family of Galois covers $f_t:X\to\mathbb{P}^n$ with Galois groups $G_t$ such that not all the $G_t$'s are conjugate? I see no intrinsic reason why they should be conjugate, but I can't seem to find any examples either. For example, if $X$ is an abelian variety then all the groups are conjugate in this situation (this follows from the main result of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.00028.pdf, for example).

Comment: You can easily find a curve $X$ with two automorphisms of order 2 and 3 (say), such that both quotients are isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$. Wouldn't that give an example?

Comment: Just to clarify, by a Galois cover, you mean that it could be ramified right? Do you fix the ramification locus on $\mathbb P^n$?

Comment: Do you want a continuous (and maybe flat) family? Otherwise, take the family of covers $f_n \colon \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$ given by $[x:y] \mapsto [x^n : y^n]$. The Galois group of $f_n$ is $\mathbb{Z}_n$, so none of these groups are conjugate in $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^1)$, since they have pairwise different orders.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Thanks for the comments; yes I am looking for a continuous (and hopefully flat) family. I have edited the question to make it more precise.

Comment: @Asvin Yes, it definitely can be ramified. I don't care if the branch locus is fixed or not.

Comment: @abx Thanks, as I just wrote I am looking for a continuous family. This automatically leaves curves out of the question.